# Equally-spaced DIVs with variable width in one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an unknown number of divs (sometimes 3, sometimes 6) which have a variable width.

```css
ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#navigation li {
  background-color: yellow;

}
#navigation li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>E01</li>
    <li>Element02</li>
    <li>Ele03</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The above example shows a way how it basically works. But what I need is a way that the elements gets a padding left and right half the width of the space between two elements so that basically the yellow background touches the one of the elements next to it. But I can't figure out how I can achieve this.

I tried a lot of approaches. (flexbox, table-cell, floats) But I never found a way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `flex-grow` property on your `li`. This will not add padding, but force the flex items to increase in width to fill the space. You can then adjust the content as needed. See [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp).

For example:

```css
ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#navigation li {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#navigation li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>E01</li>
    <li>Element02</li>
    <li>Ele03</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```